# A nbd of identity $V$ such that $V V^{-1 }$ is contained in another nbd of identity

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $D$ be a discret subgroup of center and $U$ be nbd of identity such that $U \cap D$ contains only identity. I want to find a nbd $V$ of identity such that $V V^{-1} \subset U.$ I have considered the map $G \times G \to G : (a,b) \mapsto ab^{-1}.$ This map is smooth, in particulare continous. So the set $ \{ (a,b) : a b^{-1} \in U \} $ is open. I have tried to construct required $V$ from $W$ considering projections but I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $U$ a neighborhood of the identity $e$ in $G$.  We know $(a,b) \mapsto ab^{-1}$ is continuous at $(e,e)$.  And $ee^{-1}=e$.  So there exist neighborhoods $V_1, V_2$ of $e$ so that:
$$
\forall a \in V_1, \forall b \in V_2,\qquad ab^{-1} \in U.
$$
Let $V = V_1 \cap V_2$.  So $V$ is a neighborhood of $e$.  Then of course
$V \subseteq V_1$ and $V \subseteq V_2$.

We claim $VV^{-1} \subseteq U$.  Indeed, let $c \in VV^{-1}$.  There exists $a,b \in V$ with $c=ab^{-1}$.  Then $a \in V_1$ and $b \in V_2$,
so $ab^{-1} \in U$.

---

Perhaps first prove the following, it you do not know it already.  (The "neighborhood" definition of continuity.)
Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Let$f : X \to Y$.  Let $x_0 \in X$.  Then The following are equivalent:
$\bullet\;$ $f$ is continuous at $x_0$
$\bullet\;$ for every neighborhood $U$ of $f(x_0)$ in $Y$, there exists a neighorhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $X$ with $f(V) \subseteq U$.

Comment: Can you more precisely tell how will you get $V_1$ and $V_2.$ If the function $f$ is $f(a,b) = ab^{-1} $ then $f^{-1}(U) = \{ (a,b) : ab^{-1} \in U \}$ is open, so are you taking projections of $f^{-1} U$ , but in that case what ensures that projections are not full of $G?.$

Comment: No projection involved.  A neighborhood base for $(r,s)) \in X \times Y$ consists of all products $V_1 \times V_2$, where $V_1$ is a neighborhood of $r$ in $X$ and  $V_2$ is a neighborhood of $s$ in $Y$.  (The "neighborhood" definition of the product topology.)